# Is it a good idea to have too many named locks?

Tags: mysql, java, concurrency, locking

I am using MySQL as a data store and a Java App on the top. There are many state changes that happen, and I am seeing some concurrency bugs in there.

I wanted to know if I can use named locks (GET_LOCK) for each of those connections ? At a time it can have about 6-7k of named locks. Will it effect performance ?

Or should I explore something at the application layer like zookeeper distributed locks ?

Comment: If it is about data, you can use [locking reads](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-locking-reads.html). If you only use mysql lock to synchronize your app threads, there are probably better mechanisms in java for this (some mutexes or similar)

Comment: Its not about data. Its basically synchronizing threads that are doing a lot of things apart from updating data. Standard Java concurrency mechanisms cannot be used as its a distributed system with many nodes. Either I can use distributed locks or mysql locks.

Comment: Personally I would use some distributed locking framework. GET_LOCK is quite simple and you can hold only one named lock per connection (there is a patch for it but no idea if it was merged to mysql.. http://kostja-osipov.livejournal.com/46410.html )